# OpenCV Python : No drawMatchesknn function

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, flann

When I tried to use drawMatchesKnn function as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python-Tutorials/blob/master/source/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.rst) for FLANN feature matching, I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawMatchesKnn'

I checked with other resources that drawMatchesKnn method is present in opencv.

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OpenCV Version : 2.4.7

Comment: Use opencv version 3.x. Build from source in master branch

Comment: `IMP - This tutorial is meant for OpenCV 3x version. Not OpenCV 2x`, it says clearly on the README page. You didn't read that?

Comment: @bad_keypoints actually the tutorials don't work in 2x or 3x. The tutorials are filled with calls like this `cv2.SIFT()`that don't exist in 3x (needs to be compiled with contrilbs and callled like `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`, so the tutorials are just a mess of old and new and few really work without changes.

Answer (score 5):

The functions `cv2.drawMatches` and `cv2.drawMatchesKnn` are not available in newer versions of OpenCV 2.4. @rayryeng provided a [lightweight alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227854/4355475) which works as is for the output of `DescriptorMatcher.match`. The difference with `DescriptorMatcher.knnMatch` is that the matches are returned as a list of lists. To use the @rayryeng alternative, the matches must be extracted into a 1-D list.

For example, the [Brute-Force Matching with SIFT Descriptors and Ratio Test](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#brute-force-matching-with-sift-descriptors-and-ratio-test) tutorial could be amended as such:

```
# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
       # Removed the brackets around m 
       good.append(m)

# Invoke @rayryeng's drawMatches alternative, note it requires grayscale images
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
drawMatches(gray1,kp1,gray2,kp2,good)
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this.  I've added this to my original post to make it complete and I've linked you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenCV version 3. `drawMatchesKnn()` is present in [3.0.0-alpha](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0-alpha/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp#L923) but not in [2.4.11](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp)

That error is there, because you are using an old version of OpenCV.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of doing `good.append(m)` try `good.append([m])`