# What are keypoints in image processing?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, sift, surf, keypoint

When using OpenCV for example, algorithms like SIFT or SURF are often used to detect keypoints. My question is what actually are these keypoints?

I understand that they are some kind of "points of interest" in an image.  I also know that they are scale invariant and are circular.

Also, I found out that they have orientation but I couldn't understand what this actually is. Is it an angle but between the radius and something? Can you give some explanation? I think I need what I need first is something simpler and after that it will be easier to understand the papers.

Comment: Key-points should simply be points (x,y), imo. What describes a point and basically the region around it should be called a descriptor. Some keypoints mix those terms and they become points with an attached description vector, just like @rayryeng explained.

Comment: @William - That's a good point that many people confuse.  I'll add that to my post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Let's tackle each point one by one:

> My question is what actually are these keypoints?

Keypoints are the same thing as interest points.  They are spatial locations, or points in the image that define what is **interesting** or what **stand out** in the image.  Interest point detection is actually a subset of [**blob detection**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection), which aims to find interesting regions or spatial areas in an image. The reason why keypoints are special is because no matter how the image changes... whether the image rotates, shrinks/expands, is translated (all of these would be an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) by the way...) or is subject to distortion (i.e. a projective transformation or [homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography)), you should be able to find the **same** keypoints in this modified image when comparing with the original image.  Here's an example from a post I wrote a while ago:

[image]

<sup>Source: [module' object has no attribute 'drawMatches' opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259025/module-object-has-no-attribute-drawmatches-opencv-python/26227854#26227854)</sup>

The image on the right is a rotated version of the left image.  I've also only displayed the top 10 matches between the two images.  If you take a look at the top 10 matches, these are points that we probably would want to focus on that would allow us to remember what the image was about.  We would want to focus on the face of the cameraman as well as the camera, the tripod and some of the interesting textures on the buildings in the background.  You see that these same points were found **between the two** images and these were successfully matched.

Therefore, what you should take away from this is that these are points in the image that are interesting and that they should be found no matter how the image is distorted.

> I understand that they are some kind of "points of interest" of an image. I also know that they are scale invariant and I know they are circular.

You are correct.  Scale invariant means that no matter how you scale the image, you should still be able to find those points.

---

Now we are going to venture into the **descriptor** part.  What makes keypoints **different** between frameworks is the way you **describe** these keypoints.  These are what are known as **descriptors**.  Each keypoint that you detect has an associated descriptor that accompanies it.  Some frameworks only do a keypoint detection, while other frameworks are simply a description framework and they don't detect the points.  There are also some that do **both** - they detect **and** describe the keypoints.  SIFT and SURF are examples of frameworks that both detect and describe the keypoints.

Descriptors are primarily concerned with both the **scale** and the **orientation** of the keypoint.  The keypoints we've nailed that concept down, but we need the **descriptor** part if it is our purpose to try and match between keypoints in different images.  Now, what you mean by "circular"... that correlates with the scale that the point was detected at.  Take for example this image that is taken from the [VLFeat Toolbox tutorial](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html):

[image: VLFeat example]

You see that any points that are yellow are interest points, but some of these points have a different circle radius.  These deal with **scale**.  How interest points work in a general sense is that we decompose the image into multiple scales.  We check for interest points at each scale, and we combine all of these interest points together to create the final output.  The larger the "circle", the **larger** the scale was that the point was detected at.  Also, there is a line that radiates from the centre of the circle to the edge.  This is the **orientation** of the keypoint, which we will cover next.

> Also I found out that they have orientation but I couldn't understand what actually it is. It is an angle but between the radius and something?

Basically if you want to detect keypoints regardless of scale and orientation, when they talk about **orientation** of keypoints, what they really mean is that they search a pixel neighbourhood that surrounds the keypoint and figure out how this pixel neighbourhood is oriented or what direction this patch is oriented in.  It depends on what descriptor framework you look at, but the general jist is to detect the most dominant [orientation of the gradient angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient#Mathematics) in the patch.  This is important for **matching** so that you can match keypoints together.  Take a look at the first figure I have with the two cameramen - one rotated while the other isn't.  If you take a look at some of those points, how do we figure out how one point matches with another?  We can easily identify that the top of the cameraman as an interest point matches with the rotated version because we take a look at points that **surround** the keypoint and see what orientation all of these points are in... and from there, that's how the orientation is computed.

Usually when we want to detect keypoints, we just take a look at the locations.  However, if you want to **match** keypoints between images, then you definitely need the scale and the orientation to facilitate this.

Answer (score 29):

I'm not as familiar with SURF, but I can tell you about SIFT, which SURF is based on. I provided a few notes about SURF at the end, but I don't know all the details.

---

[SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) aims to find highly-distinctive locations (or *keypoints*) in an image. The locations are not merely 2D locations on the image, but locations in the image's *scale space*, meaning they have three coordinates: **x**, **y**, and **scale**. The process for finding SIFT keypoints is:

1. blur and resample the image with different blur widths and sampling rates to create a scale-space
2. use the [difference of gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) method to detect blobs at different scales; the blob centers become our keypoints at a given **x**, **y**, and **scale**
3. assign every keypoint an **orientation** by calculating a histogram of gradient orientations for every pixel in its neighborhood and picking the orientation bin with the highest number of counts
4. assign every keypoint a 128-dimensional **feature vector** based on the gradient orientations of pixels in 16 local neighborhoods

Step 2 gives us scale invariance, step 3 gives us rotation invariance, and step 4 gives us a "fingerprint" of sorts that can be used to identify the keypoint. Together they can be used to match occurrences of the same feature at any orientation and scale in multiple images.

---

[SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features) aims to accomplish the same goals as SIFT but uses some clever tricks in order to increase speed.

For blob detection, it uses the [determinant of Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection#The_determinant_of_the_Hessian) method. The dominant orientation is found by examining the horizontal and vertical responses to [Haar wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet). The feature descriptor is similar to SIFT, looking at orientations of pixels in 16 local neighborhoods, but results in a 64-dimensional vector.

SURF features can be calculated up to 3 times faster than SIFT features, yet are just as robust in most situations.

---

For reference:

[A good SIFT tutorial](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/)

[An introduction to SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html)

Comment: Very nice.  Totally love the `tl;dr` differences between SURF and SIFT.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, though it's only because I don't really know enough to say anything more. ;) I haven't really used SURF before.

Comment: I would have never known!  BTW, the SIFT tutorial is a classic.  That's the first thing I read before Lowe's paper.

Comment: @rayryeng Author of the tutorial here - glad to hear you liked it!

Comment: @UtkarshSinha I love your work and AI Shack. Keep writing!

Comment: Comment by [Haydon Berrow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6877597/haydon-berrow) incorrectly passed as answer "The link to 'An introduction to SURF' is dead but a beta-version link is http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html"

Comment: This is succinct and much better than the accepted answer because it explains the definition of an "interesting" region (= blob detection). Thanks hugely!

Comment: @jtlz2 If you're the one who downvoted my answer, it would have been nice if you left a comment regarding your downvote.  That would help me improve my answer.