# What is difference between features and keypoints in computer vision?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, keypoint

I am studying something about some possibilities of OpenCV object detection and this is confusing to me. I just don't see the difference between these two.

Comment: See also [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10424)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are keypoints in image processing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133085/what-are-keypoints-in-image-processing)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Image features are small patches that are useful to compute similarities between images.  An **image feature** is usually composed of a feature **keypoint** and a feature **descriptor**.

The keypoint usually contains the patch 2D position and other stuff if available such as scale and orientation of the image feature.

The **descriptor** contains the visual description of the patch and is used to compare the similarity between image features.

Comment: @NAmorim an example would help make things more clear!