# Image processing on opencv keypoints

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0

I'm working on detection of blobs and doing image processing (like histogram analysis) on them. Although I detected the blobs using OpenCV `SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)`, Now I want to perform image processing/analysis on each and every blob detected.

After reading the image in grayscale (and storing it in `im` variable) I have written the following operation to detect blobs

```
# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 200;

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 200

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.30


# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.5

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.001

#now let us do blob analysis
#Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

#Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

This gives the following image:

[Output Image After Blob Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NODS2.png)

From what I understand, the `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)` outputs keypoints. The variable type of each keypoints is `cv2.keypoint`. I tried to understand what keypoints are from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133085/what-are-keypoints-in-image-processing) but that did not help much. I would appreciate if someone shows me a direction as to how to analyze (image processing like histogram analysis) the region inside keypoints (or in this case, the blobs).

Comment: you can see these links https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/  , https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/  , https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: I have gone through both the link before but that did not help. I have no idea how to analyze the key points detected in the image