# How to get pixel coordinates from Feature Matching in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matching, feature-detection

I need to get the list of the `x` and `y` coordinates of the pixels that the feature matcher selects in the code provided.  I'm using Python and OpenCV.  Can anyone help me?

```
img1=cv2.imread('DSC_0216.jpg',0)
img2=cv2.imread('DSC_0217.jpg',0)

orb=cv2.ORB(nfeatures=100000)
kp1,des1=orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2=orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

img1kp=cv2.drawKeypoints(img1,kp1,color=(0,255,0),flags=0)
img2kp=cv2.drawKeypoints(img2,kp2,color=(0,255,0),flags=0)
cv2.imwrite('m_img1.jpg',img1kp)
cv2.imwrite('m_img2.jpg',img2kp)

bf=cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches=bf.match(des1,des2)
matches=sorted(matches, key= lambda x:x.distance)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We know that your keypoints are stored in `kp1` and `kp2` where they are lists of feature matches for the first and second image respectively.  In the `cv2.ORB` perspective, the feature descriptors are 2D matrices where each row is a keypoint that is detected in the first and second image.

In your case because you are using `cv2.BFMatch`, `matches` returns a list of `cv2.DMatch` objects where each object contains several members and among them are two important members:

- `queryIdx` - The index or **row** of the `kp1` interest point matrix that matches
- `trainIdx` - The index or **row** of the `kp2` interest point matrix that matches

Therefore, `queryIdx` and `trainIdx` tell you which ORB features match between the first and second image. You'd use these to index into `kp1` and `kp2` and obtain the `pt` member, which is a tuple of `(x,y)` coordinates that determine the actual spatial coordinates of the matches.

All you have to do is iterate through each `cv2.DMatch` object in `matches`, append to a list of coordinates for both `kp1` and `kp2` and you're done.

Something like this:

```
# Initialize lists
list_kp1 = []
list_kp2 = []

# For each match...
for mat in matches:

    # Get the matching keypoints for each of the images
    img1_idx = mat.queryIdx
    img2_idx = mat.trainIdx

    # x - columns
    # y - rows
    # Get the coordinates
    (x1, y1) = kp1[img1_idx].pt
    (x2, y2) = kp2[img2_idx].pt

    # Append to each list
    list_kp1.append((x1, y1))
    list_kp2.append((x2, y2))
```

Note that I could have just done `list_kp1.append(kp1[img1_idx].pt)` and the same for `list_kp2`, but I wanted to make it very clear on how to interpret the spatial coordinates.  You could also go one step further and do a list comprehension:

```
list_kp1 = [kp1[mat.queryIdx].pt for mat in matches] 
list_kp2 = [kp2[mat.trainIdx].pt for mat in matches]
```

`list_kp1` will contain the spatial coordinates of a feature point that matched with the corresponding position in `list_kp2`.  In other words, element `i` of `list_kp1` contains the spatial coordinates of the feature point from `img1` that matched with the corresponding feature point from `img2` in `list_kp2` whose spatial coordinates are in element `i`.

---

As a minor sidenote, I used this concept when I wrote a workaround for [`drawMatches`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html#drawmatches) because for OpenCV 2.4.x, the Python wrapper to the C++ function does not exist, so I made use of the above concept in locating the spatial coordinates of the matching features between the two images to write my own implementation of it.

Check it out if you like!

[module' object has no attribute 'drawMatches' opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259025/module-object-has-no-attribute-drawmatches-opencv-python/26227854#26227854)