# An alternative for cv2.drawMatches()?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I am using OpenCV 2.4.11 with python and it does not support cv2.drawMatches().
I am trying to run Feature matching algorithms for some analysis which are available in [OpenCV-Python Tutorials](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher).
Obviously i get the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawMatches'

So i found a similar post([module' object has no attribute 'drawMatches' opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259025/module-object-has-no-attribute-drawmatches-opencv-python)) on SO where '@rayryeng' gave an alternative to cv2.drawMatches() and it works great but however it only takes exactly 5 arguments.

So i can't get it to run with these algorithms :
FLANN based Matcher, Feature Matching + Homography to find Objects.

I think some modification could get it to work but i have minimal Knowledge on this.

So any help on this is appreciated, thank you!