# Using OpenCV in Android to find an image match

Tags: opencv, android-studio, image-processing

I am trying to build an Android application that compares a photo taken by the device camera to find a match in a set of images.
I have configured OpenCV on Android Studio, but that is quite it.
Could someone please help by linking to resources or suggesting tutorials?
The OpenCV documentation does not have anything on Android Studio and the sample codes seem to be in C++.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to do the same things... I've searched some samples on GitHub but I've not found almost anything useful... These are some links:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sift+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=opencv+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: Those links are garbage. They don't address the OP's problem.  The first link finds all Android repos that implement SIFT. The second link finds any repos that use OpenCV and Android. None of those address the OP's problem.

Comment: I've told him that I've not found almost anything useful... that's all

Answer (score 1):

we have almost the same project. this links might help

https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator

https://medium.com/@akshikawijesundara/object-recognition-with-opencv-on-android-6435277ab285

in OpenCV there are plenty algorithm that we can use to find image match such as BRISK, ORB, FREAK, SIFT and SURF (SIFT and SURF available only in nonfree version since those algorithm patented).

I hope this will help